# remove json object spcefic value in the response

Tags: spring, boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bVfK.jpg)

please guide me how to do this type of implementation in spring boot project ,
given image data in json format response .

Comment: You would need to provide more details, the questions is not very clear. Are you looking for help to format your json ? It could be easily achieved using any of the popular json libraries like Jackson, Gson etc.

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonIgnore` annotation marks a property to be ignored during the serialization to JSON. If you don't want to read some field from a JSON object, then in the model, you just need to use the `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

Comment: how to use @JsonIgnore annotation on to json response entity please guide me

Comment: you can refere to the below link, which expalined with example.https://bushansirgur.in/jackson-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotation-with-example/

Comment: i don't want to remove form coding level , when i will get response in the string variable in this variable i want to remove some json values as given in image which i have shared .